# How to change network connection type on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I'm trying to change my network type from public to private/domain for my VM Workstation network connection in Windows 8 and I can't figure out how to do this.

I have tried the instructions here, but they don't work: http://www.walkernews.net/2013/02/04/how-to-change-network-type-in-windows-8/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is is the network "detected", or does it have a name of "Unidentified Network"?

Comment: What about it didn't work.  I followed the directions and it did

Comment: It is unidentified network. @Ramhound, I'm not able to right click. I think it has to do with my corporate network settings or something.

Comment: @BlaineOmega - Sounds like your domain policy prevents it, talk to your domain administrator, about changing the policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just reimaged my sole Windows 8 machine, but how I solved this problem was:

Go to "Network and Sharing Center" (right-click network icon on desktop view, or a plethora of other ways)

Select "Choose homegroup and sharing options" (that's the Windows 7 verbiage anyways.) That's the third icon down in the main part of the screen.
[image: Windows 7 Network and Sharing Center]
Under Windows 8 there's an option to "change this network type to home" if it is currently on public, because Windows won't like doing Homegroups on a Public network. You don't have to do anything with Homegroups if you don't want to, but this will help you get off of "Public."

Answer (score 1):

None of these suggestions worked for me.  Choose homegroup and sharing options was not availabe.  I found that you can do it from an administrative powershell session with the Set-NetConnectionProfile command:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name "Unidentified Network" -NetworkCategory Private
```